# NHibernate.MappingException on table insertion

Tags: nhibernate-mapping

The table structure is :

[image]

The controller action to insert a row to table is 
public bool CreateInstnParts(string data)
        {
            IDictionary myInstnParts = DeserializeData(data);

```
        try
        {
            HSInstructionPart objInstnPartBO = new HSInstructionPart();
            using (ISession session = Document.OpenSession())
            {
                using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    objInstnPartBO.DocumentId = Convert.ToInt32(myInstnParts["documentId"]);
                    objInstnPartBO.InstructionId = Convert.ToInt32(myInstnParts["instructionId"]);
                    objInstnPartBO.PartListId = Convert.ToInt32(myInstnParts["part"]);
                    objInstnPartBO.PartQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(myInstnParts["quantity"]);
                    objInstnPartBO.IncPick = Convert.ToBoolean(myInstnParts["incpick"]);
                    objInstnPartBO.IsTracked = Convert.ToBoolean(myInstnParts["istracked"]);

                    objInstnPartBO.UpdatedBy = User.Identity.Name;
                    objInstnPartBO.UpdatedAt = DateTime.Now;
                    session.Save(objInstnPartBO);

                    transaction.Commit();
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is throwing an exception

NHibernate.MappingException was caught
  Message="No persister for: Hexsolve.Data.BusinessObjects.HSInstructionPart"
  Source="NHibernate"
  StackTrace:
       at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl.GetEntityPersister(String entityName)
       at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.GetEntityPersister(String entityName, Object obj)
       at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractSaveEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedId(Object entity, String entityName, Object anything, IEventSource source, Boolean requiresImmediateIdAccess)
       at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
       at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveEventListener.SaveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
       at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.EntityIsTransient(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
       at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveEventListener.PerformSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
       at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.OnSaveOrUpdate(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
       at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireSave(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
       at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Save(Object obj)
       at HexsolveMVC.Controllers.InstructionController.CreateInstnParts(String data) in F:\Project\HexsolveMVC\Controllers\InstructionController.cs:line 1342
  InnerException:

Can anyone help me solve this??

Comment: How did you map your class ? did you use an hbm file in the resources ? are this file marked as "Embedded resource" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably miss the hbm mapping file. Did you remember to put the "Embedded Resource" compiltion flag on your mapping file ?